# Issue w/ period symbol in ag-grid pressed on numpad in IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in my angular project. 
The main idea is to make table editable w/ numeric values. If user presses any number or period/minus keys the cell should become editable.
There is a problem w/ IE and numpad period key. When NumLock is on period key at numpad is not working. It seems like IE doesn't catch that the key was pressed. I have never got into this code:

```
this.eInput.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
```

It works well in Chrome. Also period key at main part of keyboard works well both in IE, Chrome.
The same issue exists in example on ag-grid Cell Editors doc page - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/#cell-editing-example .

Any way to solve this?